# Почему закрыт исходящий порт 1433?

Tags: tcp-ip, порты, sql

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно соединяться с удаленными sql серверами, но для этого нужен порт 1433. Почему-то у меня он заблокировал. Добавлял в брандмауэре пропуск для этого порта, даже отключал брандмауэр, но конкретно этот порт не выходит в сеть. Тестировал через telnet  запрос. Может ли это быть из-за провайдера и что в таком случае можно сделать? Пытаюсь это провернуть из компьютера с управлением win 7 со статическим ip. Спасибо!

Comment: скажите ip удалённого хоста с портом 1433

Comment: Вопрос можно закрыть. Узнал в провайдера, что это они закрыли порты.

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается уже ответили в комментах, не углядел.
Но всё равно оставлю, может кому будет полезно.
• • • • • •
см. netstat
она покажет порт и кто его юзает - по ID процесса, если 0, то это система.
От этого, думаю, и исходить надо.